# Javascript fails when requiring a module within a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am attempting to require a module dynamically and I am failing at it. If I require the module from a variable or from an object key, it doesn't work, if I do it directly it works. It is a css module so I need to do it with require. That's how it works.

```
import moment, { Moment } from 'moment';

const springThemeStyles = require('../../../styles/spring.theme.scss');

interface Theme {
  theme: string;
  endDate: Date;
  startDate: Date;
  siteCode: string;
  costCenter: string;
  bannerImage: string;
  cssOverride: string;
}

const validateDate = (date: string): Moment => {
  return moment(`${moment().year()}/${date}`);
};

export const themes: Theme[] = [{
  siteCode: '',
  costCenter: '',
  theme: 'spring',
  bannerImage: 'spring.jpg',
  endDate: moment(validateDate('6/19')).toDate(),
  startDate: moment(validateDate('3/20')).toDate(),
  cssOverride: springThemeStyles
}];

export const getActiveTheme = (): any => {
  const now = moment().toDate();

  return themes.map((t: Theme) => {
    if (t.startDate >= now || t.endDate <= now) {
      // return t.cssOverride; THIS DOESN'T WORK

      return require('../../../styles/spring.theme.scss') // THIS WORKS
    }
  });
};
```

So the commented line `// return t.cssOverride; THIS DOESN'T WORK` is actually how I need it to work in order to make it dynamic.

Another thing I noticed is that if I return `t.cssOverride;` then TS complains exactly on this line `return themes.map((t: Theme)` it says `Not all code paths return a value.ts(7030)`.

The thing is that I need it to make it work like this:

```
    if (t.startDate >= now || t.endDate <= now) {
      return t.cssOverride; // THIS DOESN'T WORK     
    }
```

So I can make it dynamic. I am supposing that the `themes` array will grow and I don't have to make too much effort on maintaining this piece of code.

So any ideas?

Comment: The warning is because you don't return anything if the date conditions aren't met. You should add an `else` clause to return a default value when the date is outside the date range.

Comment: Something as simple as `else { return null; }`

Comment: Hi, @Barmar ok I fixed that. Now I need to fix the main issue. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a bundler like webpack that doesn't allow computed strings for `require()`?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what "doesn't work" means? What is it supposed to do, what does it do instead?

Comment: @jfriend00 Where do you see a computed string?

Comment: @Barmar it is just not applying the styles when I do `return t.cssOverride;` but when I do `return require('../../../styles/spring.theme.scss');` it works. So I am trying to figure out why. I don't have an idea.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00 yes I am using webpack.

Comment: Did you look at what `t.cssOverride` actually is at the point you're trying to return it?  Is it the module you want it to be?  I'm wondering if webPack is having a problem initializing that properly.

Comment: @jfriend00 well if you look at the comments and my post: it is just not applying the styles when I do `return t.cssOverride;` but when I do `return require('../../../styles/spring.theme.scss');` it works. So what could be different from calling the module directly or from an object key?

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  You need to compare `t.cssOverride` with `require('../../../styles/spring.theme.scss')` and see what is the difference between those two values since one works and the other doesn't.  That would give you an idea what's going on.  This is elemental debugging to see if this sheds some light on what's going on.